# Problem with launching player opposite of Line Renderer with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want my player to be launched opposite of a line renderer that I made. The line renderer works fine and is  how I want it to be. But I was unable to try and make the physics work. I've been looking through Unity documentation and posts online but still no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Line Launching Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineLaunching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float power;
    public float dragLength;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public LineRenderer lineRend;
    public Camera cam;

    private Vector3 startPoint;
    private Vector3 endPoint;

    private Vector2 force;

    void Awake()
    {
        power = 100f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            startPoint = gameObject.transform.position;
            startPoint.z = 15;
            Vector3 currentPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            currentPoint.z = 15;
            RenderLine(startPoint, currentPoint);

            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }


        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            endPoint.z = 15;

            if (startPoint.x > endPoint.x && startPoint.y > endPoint.y)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(startPoint.x - endPoint.x * power * Time.deltaTime, startPoint.y - endPoint.y * power * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (startPoint.x > endPoint.x && startPoint.y < endPoint.y)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(startPoint.x - endPoint.x * power * Time.deltaTime, endPoint.y - startPoint.y * power * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (startPoint.x < endPoint.x && startPoint.y > endPoint.y)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(endPoint.x - startPoint.x * power * Time.deltaTime, startPoint.y - endPoint.y * power * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (startPoint.x < endPoint.x && startPoint.y < endPoint.y)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(endPoint.x - startPoint.x * power * Time.deltaTime, endPoint.y - startPoint.y * power * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            lineRend.positionCount = 0;
        }
    }

    public void RenderLine(Vector3 startPoint, Vector3 endPoint)
    {
        lineRend.positionCount = 2;
        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[2];
        points[0] = startPoint;
        points[1] = Vector3.MoveTowards(startPoint, endPoint, 6.5f);
        lineRend.SetPositions(points);
        float fade = Vector2.Distance(startPoint, endPoint) / 100 * 15;

        lineRend.startColor = new Color(1.0F, fade + 1 - (fade * 2), 0.0F, 1.0F);
        lineRend.endColor = new Color(1.0F, fade + 1 - (fade * 2), 0.0F, 0.0F);
    }

}
```

Also here is a gif of what it looks like in Unity when running.

#### Gif of Unity in Runtime:

[image: Gif of Unity in Runtime]

Comment: I don’t think you need the end point variable because the current point is where the endpoint will be.

Comment: ...and do you want it to launch toward the mouse, or do you want it to go in the opposite direction of the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the direction vector from your `start` to `end` and negate it. It should give you the exact opposite direction you are aiming. It would also reduce the complex if checks you do are doing for velocity. I would also recommend using `AddForce` instead of setting velocity directly so if you want other outside forces acting on the object, they are not overridden by this code.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    endPoint.z = 15;

    Vector2 negatedDirection = (startPoint - endPoint).normalized;

    rb.AddForce(negatedDirection * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    lineRend.positionCount = 0;
}
```

There is also another [`ForceMode2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode2D.html) you can use, but as it seems you want the movement to be immediate, `Impulse` is the way to go.

Comment: Doing `new Vector2(negatedDirection.x, negatedDirection.y)` is redundant though ;) simply use the `negatedDirection` .. `Vector3` and `Vecror2` are converted into each other implicitly

Comment: @derHugo Yep had just realized thanks for the correction. Also forgot to normalize the direction. Should be good now.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out. Did have to change  Vector3 negatedDirection = -(startPoint - endPoint); to Vector3 negatedDirection = startPoint - endPoint;